# How to make assign one char* to the another char*

Tags: c, pointers, makefile, char, assign

#### how to make st1 = st2 if they are both char*

```
char * string1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
char * string2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
string1 = "hello";
string2 = "world";

string1 = string2; // error in the future code
```

#### how to appropriately make that happen?

Comment: string1= string2 is correct, even if I think you are looking for strcpy()

Comment: The code you've shown has several mistakes. Also, this looks like an XY problem. Could you elaborate on what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: You have a memory leak. After you assign the pointers to dynamically-allocated memory, you overwrite them with pointers to the string literals.

Comment: `char *string1 = malloc(sizeof (char))` is almost certainly a mistake.  You have just allocated enough space to store exactly one char.  If you want to use it to store a string, you have enough space for only the empty string (you can only store the null terminator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char * string1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Do not do that. That allocates space for a single character and sets `string1` to point to that space. That is almost never useful in a program. Usually, you want to set a `char *` to point to more space than a single character, because you are going to work with more than a single character. Or you can set `string1` to be `NULL`, which indicates it does not currently point to anything.

```
char * string1 = malloc(sizeof(char));
char * string2 = malloc(sizeof(char));
string1 = "hello";
```

This causes a “memory leak,” meaning that the program has lost track of the memory allocated by `malloc`.

A string literal such as `"hello"` is in effect an array of `char` that exists for the entire time the program is running. When used in an expression like this, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the first character of that array. So `string1 = "hello";` sets `string1` to the address of that character. This causes it to forget about its previous value, from `malloc(sizeof(char))`.

```
string1 = string2; // error in the future code
```

This may or may not be wrong. It sets `string1` to point to the same place as `string2`. So `string1` and `string2` will then be pointing to the same string, so they are of course pointing to equal strings, since the string equals itself.

Sometimes when working with pointers to `char`, we want to change the pointer to point to a different string, but sometimes we want to copy a string from one place to another. So, whether `string1 = string2;` is the right thing for your program depends on what you are trying to do. You would need to provide much more information in your question about the context and what you are trying to do in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcpy()` to copy strings.

```
char *string1 = malloc(6);
char *string2 = malloc(6);

strcpy(string1, "hello");
strcpy(string2, "world");

strcpy(string1, string2);
```

Make sure you allocate enough space for the longest string you're going to copy, plus an extra byte for the null terminator.